# Can I mix grouped and ungrouped Solr results?

Tags: solr, grouping, solr4

So I have a set of documents in my Solr index. Say I have three content types: *articles*, *editorials* and *statistics*. These are indexed as Solr documents and are all retrievable in equal fashion.

Each published *statistic* is really composed of several separate documents, indexed separately. Now I've created a field in solr called "**grouping**" which is populated through metadata, linking these related documents together.

So I have articles and editorials that I want to list in my search result like an ungrouped set of documents, and then I only want to create groups for the sets of documents that share the same "**grouping**" field value. Looking at my solr index, the documents that are not *statistics* don't have this field. It shouldn't be mandatory.

The intention of this grouping is to collect all of the separate documents in a tidy bundle to avoid them littering the result list, and to allow the user to drill down into the results. A *statistic* can consist of dozens of separate documents.

However, when I try using this configuration:

```
<str name="group">true</str>
<str name="group.field">grouping</str>
<str name="group.limit">3</str>
```

Solr returns a group of three documents with groupValue at Null, and then the rest of the results are the expected groups of three or fewer documents of with a common **Grouping** value, and that's the end of the result list.

My question is, can I combine grouped and ungrouped results in any way, so that I might get, say, five results without any grouping value returned as though there was no grouping turned on, and then a group of 'statistics', followed by the rest of the results?

Please let me know if anything is unclear or if further examples are needed :)

Comment: My solution was to just give all the content a unique **Grouping** value. I basically just copied the ID value the content already had at index build time, except for the *statistics* pages.
I'll mark this as my answer if nobody else comes up with anything :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was to just give all the content a unique Grouping value. I basically just copied the ID value the content already had at index build time, except for the statistics pages.

Grouping all content on this value puts each page that were not supposed to be grouped in a separate group of its' own, assuring that the content that *were* supposed to end up in a group was always unique and well sorted.

Thanks, Internet!

```
You're welcome. 

-the Internet.
```